# Loop (which stores items in collection) seems to iterate less times that it should?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to add 60 things to localstorage. Inside the for loop I'm creating an object, converting it to a string and adding it to localstorage, with the time as a key.

```
function populate()
{
    for(var i=0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        var newDate = new Date();
        var card = {
            'name': i,
            'cost': i,
            'type': i,
            'text': i,
            'power': i,
            'toughness': i};    
        localStorage.setItem(newDate.getTime(), JSON.stringify(card));
    }
}
```

Logic dictates this should happen 60 times. In practise it happens between about 2 and 20 times, and the values of i given to the object's attributes vary greatly. Sometimes I get 2 with values of 11 and 59, sometimes I get 18 with numbers from 1 up to 59 or 60. This for loop does not iterate as many times as it should, but it doesn't even do it in order, it seems to be random.

What is going on here?

Comment: could possibly fix this with a "is later" if statement

Comment: You need to post the code for localStorage.setItem. The problem is likely there. Probably the key is a duplicate because the iterations occur too fast.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are running into issues with overlapping times and so the duplicates are not inserted. This will separate the duplicates. You may choose a different implementation or a GUID, which is up to your discretion.

```
function populate()
{
for(var i=0; i < 60; i++)
{
    var newDate = new Date();
    var card = {
        'name': i,
        'cost': i,
        'type': i,
        'text': i,
        'power': i,
        'toughness': i};    
    localStorage.setItem("" + i + newDate.getTime(), JSON.stringify(card));
}
}
```

Comment: To clarify, this means that multiple iterations of the loop can happen within the same millisecond, so `newDate.getTime()` has the same value when different ones are expected, so some "card" values get overwritten by later ones.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding why it happens refer to Traviss' answer but how to solve it without changing your key as I am guessing you might want to refer it by the time you could do this:

```
function populate()
{
    for(var i=0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        var newDate = new Date();
        var card = {
            'name': i,
            'cost': i,
            'type': i,
            'text': i,
            'power': i,
            'toughness': i};    
        setTimeout(function(){localStorage.setItem(newDate.getTime(), JSON.stringify(card));},1);
    }

}
```